Being explicit about the kernel of the map $R[x,y]\to \frac{R}{I}[x,y]$ and coefficients of $\frac{R}{I}[x,y]$
The following is taken from the text University Algebra by: N.S Gopalkrishnan
Background
Exercise 17:  Let $I$ be an ideal of a commutative ring $R$ and let $I[x,y]$ consist of those polynomials with coefficients in $I$.  Show that $I[x,y]$ is an ideal of $R[x,y]$ and that $\frac{R[x,y]}{I[x,y]}\backsimeq (\frac{R}{I})[x,y]$.

Solution: $I[x,y]$ can be erified to be an ideal using the fact that $*$ is an ideal in $R$.  Consider the projection map $R\to \frac{R}{I}$.  This induces a ring homomorphnism $R[x,y]\to \frac{R}{I}[x,y]$ which is "onto" and has kernel $I[x,y]$.  Hence $\frac{R[x,y]}{I[x,y]}\backsimeq (\frac{R}{I})[x,y]$

Questions
In the above quoted solution, if I want to be a bit more explict about what the kernel of the map $R[x,y]\to \frac{R}{I}[x,y]$ look like other than simply saying that it is $I[x,y]$.  By explicit, I mean terms of the notation for multivariable polynomial $\sum_{i,j}r_{ij}x^iy^j=\sum_j(\sum_i r_{ij}x^i)y^j$.  I know that $(R[x])[y]\backsimeq (R[y])[x]\backsimeq R[x,y]$, so is the coefficient of the multivariable polynomial $\sum_{i,j}r_{ij}x^iy^j\in (\frac{R}{I})[x,y]$ be written as
(1) $(r_{ij}+I)x^iy^j$
or
(2) $(r_{ij}x^i+I)y^j$ since $(R[x])[y]\backsimeq R[x,y]$
Finally should the kernel be written in set builder notation as:
$\text{ker }\phi=\{\sum_{i,j}r_{ij}x^iy^j\in R[x,y]\mid\forall i\forall j,\tau(r_{i,j})=0_R\}= \{\sum_{i,j}r_{ij}x^iy^j\in R[x,y]\mid\forall i\forall j,r_{i,j}\in I\}=I[x,y]$
Thank you in advance
